# Entity framework 6 filter child object

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to get data from database with use of EF6.
I have two classes

```
public class Manufacturer
{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public bool Enabled {get;set;}
  public virtual IList<Product> Products {get;set;}
}

public class Product
{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public bool Enabled {get;set;}
  public virtual Manufacturer Manufacturer {get;set;}
}
```

I need to get only Enabled Manufacturer with Enabled Products
I tried the folowing:

```
var results = _context.Manufacturer
              .Where(m => m.Enabled)
              .Where(m => m.Products.Any(p => p.Enabled))
              .Select(m => new
              {
                  Manufacturer = m;
                  Product = m.Products.Where(p => p.Enabled)
              });
```

Unfortunaly child object are not filltered.
"Products" list is alyways filled with products that are not "Enabled"
Any idea?

Comment: You can't use navigation properties to access subset of related entities.

Comment: I was afraid of something like this. I'm going to use Dapper for basic data access

Answer (score 1):

you could go the other way around. also try including the related object.

```
var r = context.Products.Include("Manufacturer")
               .Where(p=>p.Enabled && p.Manufacturer.Enabled);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this. But i have cheked your code and it works as well. I dont know why you getting not enabled products...

```
var manufacturers = (from o in _context.Manufacturer
                      where o.Enabled
                      select
                      new
                      {
                          manufacturers  = o,
                          products = o.Products.Where(c=>c.Enabled).ToList()
                      }).ToList();
```